# Kibana url is not working in web browser but in server kibana status is running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am new to kibana. I did setup and it started working fine before. 
But now I am having issue while accessing http://10.xx.xx.xx:5601/, it is giving site can't be reached in web browser.
And I haven't modified anything.

But in server kibana status is normal like below

```
xxxx# service kibana status
kibana is running
```

And in server when I did curl check with url it is giving **302 found**

```
[root@elkapp ~]# curl -X GET 'http://10.xx.xx.xx:5601/' -v
```

Please help me in understanding what is the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the port accessible outside the server?

Comment: What is the value of `server.host` in `kibana.yml`? Also what output you get for the following command `netstat -nltp | grep 5601`

Comment: Server. Host: 'my server

Comment: And for the netstat command, I could see port **listen**.

Comment: 10.x.x.x IP addresses are private addresses, so it's unlikely that you can access them from outside. You need to open an SSH tunnel between your host and your server.

Comment: If that's the case, it shouldn't work before also. It was working fine while ago. Recently it suddenly stopped working.